# How to split for only one string without using arrays

Tags: c#, .net

I've a string `01-India`. I want to split on '-' and get only the code 01. How can I do this. I'm a .net newbie. Split function returns a array. Since I need only one string, how can this be done. Is there a ingenious way to do it using split only. Or do I've to use `substring` only?

Comment: FYI, your question has nothing to do with ASP.NET or C#. It's purely a .NET question, as the `System.String` type is part of .NET.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Other possibility is

```
string xy = "01-India";
string xz = xy.Split('-')[0];
```

Answer (score 4):

You can search for the first occurence of - and then use the method substring to cut the piece out.

```
var result = input.Substring(0, input.IndexOf('-'))
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
var s = "01-India";
var result = s.SubString(0, s.IndexOf("-"));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
string str = "01-India";
string prefix = null;
int pos = str.IndexOf('-');
if (pos != -1)
   prefix = str.SubString(0,pos);
```

Comment: Not sure what `Substr` is, but +1 for out of range checking.

Comment: @Marc: I occasionally confuse my C++ and C# libraries.

Answer (score 2):

```
var str = "01-India";
var hyphenIndex = str.IndexOf("-");
var start = str.substring(0, hyphenIndex);
```

or you can use regular expression if it is a more complicated string pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't want to use arrays, you could do an IndexOf('-') and then a substring.

```
string s = "01-India"
int index = s.IndexOf('-');
string code = s.Substring(0, index);
```

Or, for added fun, you could use String.Remove.

```
string s = "01-India"
int index = s.IndexOf('-');
string code = s.Remove(index);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string value = "01-India";

string part1 = value.Split('-')[0];
```